# Select value in multi-column ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a popup with a listview inside:

```
    <Popup Name="PopupResultados" Width="200" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBoxBuscar}" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
        <ListView Name="listViewResultados" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" SelectionChanged="listViewResultados_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridViewResultados" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource noHeader}">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Col1" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Col2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Popup>
```

The listview is filled with a dictionary:

```
    private void buscar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<int, String> dicc = admin.buscarEntidad(textBoxBuscar.Text);

        if (!PopupResultados.IsOpen)
        {
            if (dicc.Count() != 0)
                foreach (var par in dicc)
                    listViewResultados.Items.Add(new { Col1 = par.Key, Col2 = par.Value });
            else
                listViewResultados.Items.Add(new { Col2 = "No hay coincidencias" });
            PopupResultados.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to select an item in the listview and get the integer value in Col1.

How can I get the integer value?

When I type `listViewResultados.SelectedItem.` I get only 4 methods: `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `GetType` and `ToString`.

Forgot to say that I'm trying to get the integer value inside listViewResultados_SelectionChanged

Comment: use Mvvm for this.  use Interactivity EventToCommand (for SelectionChanged).  Also, bind lists to ObservableCollection<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Cast `listViewResultados.SelectedItem` to the Type of Which your Collection Items to wich your ListView ItemsSource is binded. Like if your ItemsSource is binded to List of string then just do it like (string)listViewResultados.SelectedItem. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. I can't cast because... the other answer was deleted. :(

Comment: This was a comment to the deleted answer: I get an exception in both cases. With the first method I get an "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" exception. It's related with the line "int col1 = result.Col1;". With the second method I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception. It's related with the line "var col1 = ((ListItem)listViewResultados.SelectedItem).Col1;".